# Clay Institute Navier Stokes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vectors, matrix-equations

I'm trying to understand the Navier-Stokes Problem from the Clay Institute text here: http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/navierstokes.pdf . I've done an example problem to see what the problem is, but I don't run into any.

We are trying to satisfy:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial t} + (\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{u}=-\frac{\nabla P}{\rho} + \nu\nabla^{2}\textbf{u}+\textbf{f},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{incompr}
\nabla\cdot\textbf{u}=0.
\end{equation}

We get to pick a velocity (u) and pressure (P) function to satisfy these equations. We take $n=3$ by putting our velocity and pressure vectors in the 3D Cartesian plane with $x,y,z$. We let $\textbf{f}$ be 0 according to the problem description, and assume kinematic viscosity (nu) to be greater than 0. Let

\begin{equation}
     \textbf{u}(x,t)=\begin{bmatrix}
                x+t \\
                -2y+t \\
                z+t 
                \end{bmatrix}           
\end{equation}

Then $\textbf{u}(x,t)$ satisfies the divergence free condition because

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \textbf{u} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z}
\end{equation}

which is

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \textbf{u} = 1-2+1=0
\end{equation}

Then

\begin{equation}\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial t}=\begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\
                1 \\
                1 
                \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

And

\begin{equation}
\textbf{u} \cdot \nabla = (x+t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + (-2y+t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+(z+t)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{equation}

And

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(\textbf{u} \cdot \nabla)\textbf{u} &= (x+t)\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial x} + (-2y+t)\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial y}+(z+t)\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial z} \\
           &=(x+t)\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+(-2y+t)\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+(z+t)\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
           &= \begin{bmatrix} x+t \\ 4y-2t \\ z+t \end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since laplacian of $\textbf{u}$ is 0 the whole kinematic velocity term goes to 0. And the final Navier-Stokes expression is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} x+t \\ 4y-2t \\ z+t \end{bmatrix}=-\frac{\nabla P}{\rho}
\end{equation}

So we set $\rho$ equal to 1 for easy calculation. Bring the negative to the left hand side and combine the left hand side.

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} -x-t-1 \\ -4y+2t-1 \\ -z-t-1 \end{bmatrix}=\nabla P
\end{equation}

and we solve for a solution for P

\begin{equation}
P=\frac{-x^2}{2}-tx-x-2y^2+2ty-y-\frac{z^2}{2}-tz-z
\end{equation}

So we now have infinitely differentiable functions for u and P and they are smooth since they are polynomial. Where did I make a mistake/misunderstand the problem?

Comment: Godspeed to you.

Comment: @TheCount I don't understand?

Comment: It's a big job. I was wishing you luck. I don't know much about the NS problem myself or I would jump in.

Comment: @TheCount oh thanks! Hard to get started when you don't know they problem ;)

Comment: You have a number of misunderstandings.  The simplest to point out is the final step.  You assert that the solution $P$ is a vector quantity, but it is in fact a scalar.  Note the equation above it is a value for the *gradient* of $P$.

Comment: @hardmath I think I fixed it.

Comment: The problem is about existence and smoothness for *any* initial data, not just in a particular case.

Comment: You found a velocity/pressure field that satisfies Navier-Stokes on an unbounded domain.  This is not new.  Many exact solutions are known even with physically realistic boundary conditions.  You need to reread the statement of the Clay problem.  One aspect is that the solution must be "globally defined."  Your solution becomes infinite both spatially as $\| \mathbf{x} \| \to \infty$ and temporally at any fixed point as $t \to \infty$.  This field has infinite energy.  In particular, the Clay solution must have bounded energy $\int \| \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t)\|^2 \, d \mathbf{x} < E$.

Comment: @winther what do you mean by initial data?  What do you give me? X,y, and z? I believe the problem states that we pick u and p and we just have to prove there exists which is 1 solution.

Comment: @rrl I will look into bounded energy thanks!

Comment: To solve general PDEs we need initial conditions. By initial data I mean an initial velocity field in this case (which would allows us to evolve the solution from $t = 0$ to any time by applying the PDE). For your case $u(x,0) = (x,-2y,z)$ can be though of an initial condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context of [the Clay Institute's presentation](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems) of the Navier-Stokes equations (as subject for the Millennium Problem Prizes), your attempt most closely resembles the challenge to give a proof of statement (A):

> **(A) Existence and smoothness of Navier–Stokes solutions on $\mathbb{R}^3$.**
>   Take $\nu \gt 0$ and $n = 3$. Let $u^\circ(x)$ be any smooth, divergence-free vector field satisfying (4).  Take $f(x, t)$ to be identically zero. Then there exist smooth functions $p(x, t), u_i(x, t)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 × [0,\infty)$ that satisfy (1), (2), (3), (6), (7).

The notation of the [linked PDF](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/navierstokes.pdf) conforms closely to the notation of the Question above.  The component version of (1) there has been recast here as a vector equation above, $\textbf{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, and pressure $p$ there has been labelled $P$ here.  Also the mentions of $x$ in the PDF were intended to mean points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n=2,3$. For consistency we will adopt the notation of the Question, asking Readers to supply any necessary rewriting for comparison with the PDF.  In particular, except where quoting the PDF, our $x$ is only the first coordinate of $\mathbb{R}^3$, supplemented by variable $y,z$ as used in the Question.

As already noted by Commenters RRL and Winther, the N-S solution provided in the Question satisfies (1) and (2) but only for a specific initial condition (3):

$$ \textbf{u}^\circ(x,y,z) = (x,-2y,z) $$

and this *linear* initial condition is not "physically reasonable" as defined in the PDF's "bounded energy" restriction (7):

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |u(x,t)|^2 \textrm{d}x \lt C \;\;\text{ for all }\; t \ge 0 $$

**NB:** This is one of the cases where, in quoting the PDF, $x$ has a multidimensional meaning.

Indeed a fair reading of the linked PDF would require the proof of statement (A) to apply to *all* initial conditions satisfying (4) for some choice of $\alpha,K \gt 0$:

$$ | \partial_x^\alpha u^\circ(x) | \le C_{\alpha K} (1+|x|)^{-K} \;\;\text{ on }\mathbb{R}^n, \text{ for some positive } \alpha \text{ and } K $$

The PDF's bound (4) involves both smoothness and growth of the initial condition and leaves something to the Reader's imagination to interpret how $\alpha$ and $K$ are quantified.  However the "bounded energy" inequality (7) must also be satisfied by the initial condition by taking $t=0$, so we may confidently excluded the solution offered above from what would satisfy the Millennium Problem requirements.

---

For some background and perspective on the incompressible Navier-Stokes in the context of more general fluid flow problems, the Wikipedia article [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) is a reasonable jumping off point.

In general it should be noted that the two-dimensional problems corresponding to (A) and (B) (periodic solution) were settled by [Ladyzhenskaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olga_Ladyzhenskaya).

Much literature on the incompressible N-S equations is concerned with numerical approximation schemes, esp. finite elements.  In this context the analysis of discrete versions of the N-S equations can be understood as parallels to the continuous problem.  In that vein I would recommend my adviser's book, [Finite Element Methods for Viscous Incompressible Flows: A Guide to Theory, Practice, and Algorithms](https://books.google.com/books?id=5L9oyQQDX5gC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Max Gunzburger (2012).

Comment: I think the $1 MM prize is safe for now (+1).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to calculate bounded energy, but it will be something I look into. That integral is hard for me to follow and I'm not sure what C is. Do you know of any velocity and pressure functions which satisfy that condition? Then it would just come down to proving for all of its initial conditions?

Comment: @Seth Kitchen: Bounded energy aside for the moment, this problem is about proving for any admissible initial condition that solutions exist as mentioned above -- not just exhibiting a solution.  Consider an innocent-looking ODE and initial condition $u'(t) = u^2(t), \,\,u(0) = 1$. The unique solution near $t = 0$ is $u(t) = 1/(1-t)$ which blows up in finite time, $t = 1$.  Part of the Clay problem is to show that can't happen for N-S -- an extremely difficult problem.

Comment: @SethKitchen: The integral of the "bounded energy" condition is just the integral of the length squared $|u(x,t)|^2$ over all of $\mathbb{R}^3$; this is also known as the square of the $L^2$-norm of $u$, in your terminology. Here $C$ is merely a constant, so we are saying the "energy" remains finite for all time $t$ (since $C$ does not depend on $t$).

Comment: @hardmath do the sin/cos functions satisfy bounded energy conditions and smooth conditions? Why don't they work?

Comment: @SethKitchen: They do not satisfy bounded energy on all of $\mathbb {R}^3$, but note that some of the versions of Navier-Stokes posed in the contest involve periodic functions.

Comment: @hardmath: Let $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, Does $| \partial_x^\alpha u^\circ(x) |$ mean $| \partial_{x_i}^\alpha u^\circ(x) |$ for $i=1,2,3$?  Also for any $\alpha$ and any $K$ should be for any positive $\alpha$ and any positive $K$? right?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mike:  I tweaked the wording.  The expression $| \partial_x^\alpha u^\circ(x) |$ refers to the $L^2$-norm of the vector of (fractional) partial derivatives of order $\alpha$ on the initial condition.  You are free to specify some $\alpha,K \gt 0$ for your proof.

Comment: @hardmath: Let $\partial_{i}:=\partial_{x_i},i=1,2,3$. If $J=| \partial_x^\alpha u^\circ(x) |=\sum_{i,j=1,2,3}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}(\partial_i^\alpha u_j^\circ(x))(\partial_i^\alpha u_j^\circ(x))dx$, then $J$ is no longer a function of $x$ and it does not make sense to compare it against $C_{\alpha K}(1+|x|)^{-K}$, which is a function of $x$. I still do not quite get it.  Thanks!

Comment: @mike:  For simplicity let's take $\alpha = 1$, so that $\partial_x^\alpha u^\circ(x) $ is the gradient of $u^\circ(x)$, a vector for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$.  We are asking for an initial condition $u^\circ$ that satisfies a "physically reasonable" energy decay condition (see previous discussion) of the form $\sqrt{(\partial_1 u(x))^2 + (\partial_2 u(x))^2 + (\partial_3 u(x))^2} = ||\nabla u(x)||_2 \le C(1+|x|)^{-K}$.  This is bound on the "Euclidean length" of the gradient of $u^\circ(x)$ at each $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks a lot! I got it.