# Clay Institute Navier Stokes Part 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vectors, matrix-equations

This is an extension to my question here: [Clay Institute Navier Stokes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174742/clay-institute-navier-stokes) . Last time my solution was wrong because my velocity vector did not use bounded functions. Also someone said that I am only showing one example, but I'm trying to prove a statement that says "there exists" so I should only have to find one right? I have looked into smooth and bounded functions and it looks like Gaussian functions are good examples, so I have rewritten another example. If you could please tell me what is still wrong/not satisfactory.

We are trying to satisfy:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial t} + (\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{u}=-\frac{\nabla P}{\rho} + \nu\nabla^{2}\textbf{u}+\textbf{f},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{incompr}
\nabla\cdot\textbf{u}=0.
\end{equation}

We get to pick a velocity (u) and pressure (P) function to satisfy these equations. We take $n=3$ by putting our velocity and pressure vectors in the 3D Cartesian plane with $x,y,z$. We let $\textbf{f}$ be 0 according to the problem description, and assume kinematic viscosity (nu) to be greater than 0. Let

\begin{equation}
     \textbf{u}(x,t)=\begin{bmatrix}
                e^{-t^2} \\
                e^{-t^2} \\
                e^{-t^2} 
                \end{bmatrix}           
\end{equation}

Then $\textbf{u}(x,t)$ satisfies the divergence free condition because

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \textbf{u} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z}
\end{equation}

which is

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \textbf{u} = 0+0+0=0
\end{equation}

Then

\begin{equation}\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial t}=\begin{bmatrix}
                -2te^{-t^2} \\
                -2te^{-t^2} \\
                -2te^{-t^2} 
                \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

And

\begin{equation}
\textbf{u} \cdot \nabla = (e^{-t^2})\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + (e^{-t^2})\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+(e^{-t^2})\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{equation}

And

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(\textbf{u} \cdot \nabla)\textbf{u} &= (e^{-t^2})\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial x} + (e^{-t^2})\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial y}+(e^{-t^2})\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial z} \\
           &=(e^{-t^2})\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+(e^{-t^2})\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+(e^{-t^2})\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
           &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since laplacian of $\textbf{u}$ is 0 the whole kinematic velocity term goes to 0. And the final Navier-Stokes expression is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} -2te^{-t^2} \\ -2te^{-t^2} \\ -2te^{-t^2} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=-\frac{\nabla P}{\rho}
\end{equation}

So we set $\rho$ equal to 1 for easy calculation. Bring the negative to the left hand side and combine the left hand side.

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 2te^{-t^2} \\ 2te^{-t^2} \\ 2te^{-t^2} \end{bmatrix}=\nabla P
\end{equation}

and we solve for a solution for P

\begin{equation}
P=2 e^{-t^2} t x + 2 e^{-t^2} t y + 2 e^{-t^2} t z
\end{equation}

So we now have infinitely differentiable functions for u and P. Where did I make a mistake/misunderstand the problem? http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/navierstokes.pdf . I'm trying to prove statement A

Comment: You have shown that there is a solution in the special case $u(x,0) = (1,1,1)^T$. The problem statement asks for a proof of the existence of a smooth solution for any smooth initial data $u(x,0) = u^0(x)$.

Comment: How can I get from (1,1,1)^T to u^0 (x) ?

Comment: If I knew that, I would be very famous :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the problem.  The problem is not to show that functions $\{\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t), P(\mathbf{x},t)\}$ exist which satisfy the Navier-Stokes equations;  that much is relatively easy.  The problem is to show that given **any** function $\mathbf{u}^\circ(\mathbf{x})$, there exists functions $\{\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},t), P(\mathbf{x},t)\}$ that satisfy the Navier-Stokes equations and satisfy
$$
\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},0) = \mathbf{u}^\circ(\mathbf{x}).
$$
This function $\mathbf{u}^\circ(\mathbf{x})$ is called the *initial data*;  it basically tells you what the system is doing at the moment you start your stopwatch.

For your function, you have $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},0) = (1,1,1)$.  I haven't gone carefully through your math, but even if this were a solution of the Navier-Stokes equations, it would only be a drop in the bucket.  You'd then have to find a solution with $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},0) = (e^{-(x^2+y^2 + z^2)}, 0, 0)$.  And then $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x},0) = e^{-(x^2+y^2 + z^2)}(\sin(z^2+x), x^2, \tanh(y))$.  And then *every other conceivable function* that I could give you for the initial data.

Obviously, it's impossible to write down a solution for every conceivable function, for the simple reason that there are infinitely many such functions and you don't have an infinite amount of time.  Rather, when mathematicians are trying to prove existence of solutions to PDEs, they try to find a general solution in the form of integrals involving the initial data, and then prove that these integrals are well-behaved no matter what the initial data is.  Sometimes, they have to impose certain conditions on the initial data to make sure that their integrals are well-behaved;  these are the conditions that you ran into in your last post.

Answer (score 6):

As with many hard math problems, the trick is to prove something *always* exists.  This was a good exercise, though - you found a certain function that satisfies a nonlinear PDE, and that's not always easy to do explicitly.  Now can you find a solution that satisfies something like 
$$
{\bf u}(x,0) = {\bf u}^0(x) = \exp(-\|x\|^2)[y,-x,0]^T?
$$

Comment: could you explain or link me to some information on that notation? What does a exp(−∥x∥2)[1,1,1]^T look like?

Comment: It's a vector field with each component given by the function $\exp(-(x^2+y^2+z^2))$.

Comment: but the divergence of that field is not 0

Comment: but p would be basically integral -2*x*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 - 2*y*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 - 2*z*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 + 2*(exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)) - 2*x^2*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))) dx + integral -2*x*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 - 2*y*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 - 2*z*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 + 2*(exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)) - 2*x^2*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))) dy + integral -2*x*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 - 2*y*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 - 2*z*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2 + 2*(exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)) - 2*x^2*exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))) dz

Comment: @SethKitchen Very good point, the divergence of ${\bf u}^0$ should be zero.  I updated my ${\bf u}^0$.

Comment: Haha sorry I still don't follow the notation. What has changed? are all the components still exp(−(x^2+y^2+z^2)) ?

Comment: Now the $x$ component is $y\exp(-(x^2+y^2+z^2))$, the $y$ component is $-x\exp(-(x^2+y^2+z^2))$ and the $z$ component is zero.  You might need to refresh the page.

Comment: Ok but then the function is not bounded right? Because as x->infinity u2 goes to -infinity

Comment: No, it's definitely bounded - the Gaussian kills off any polynomial-strength growth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63873/discussion-between-seth-kitchen-and-icurays1).

Comment: @SethKitchen, are you using a computer algebra system? If so, which one? Thank you.

Comment: I like C# so I use the Math.Net Symbolics package. I haven't found anything besides wolfram that will do symbolic integration so I do everything but that in c#

Comment: @icurays1 what is the significance if I find a solution to the example you provide?

Comment: The point is, if you can find a _general_ technique and _prove_ that it works for _every_ possible initial condition satisfying the constraints discussed in the Clay problem statement, you've solved the problem and I will personally write you a check for the prize.  If you solve the equation for the _particular_ example I provided, you've only improved your own personal understanding of the problem (which is good), but you haven't solved the problem in _general_.   There is a big big difference.

Comment: Think analogously to cancer: it is possible (indeed very common and increasingly so) to cure _one person's_ cancer, but yet we cannot say that we have cured _cancer_ because our treatments don't always work.